# How to merge CSVs, w/out Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, merge

For example I have 3 files 1.csv, 2csv, 3csv. I need to merge them to one file merged.csv.

I'm struggling with this.

So far I did this

```
import csv
import glob
import os
from loguru import logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Start')

    csvFilesPath = ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']
    res = []

    for csvFilePath in csvFilesPath:                                
        logger.info(csvFilePath)                                    
        with open(csvFilePath) as csvfile:                          
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')     
            for row in csv_reader:                                  
                print(row)
```

Comment: does this need to be in python? simple bash command could do the job here.

Comment: yeah, that's should be python

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?  Open a `csv.writer` and write to it.  Are there header rows in all the CSV files?  Are they all the same?  Edit the question with sample input files and desired output file to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using DictReader in your example, I assume all input CSVs have a header—and the *same* header.

There's kind of a "chicken and egg" problem in that you need to know what the header is when you create the DictWriter that will merge the files, before you start reading.  There are ways around that, but they're hacky.

I think it's much more clear to just open the first file, read its header and create the writer, then start reading for the purposes of merging:

```py
import csv

file_paths = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"]

# Sample first file for its header
header = []
with open(file_paths[0], newline="") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    header = reader.fieldnames

# Create writer with header
f_out = open("merged.csv", "w", newline="")
writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=header)

# Start iterating, reading, merging
for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, newline="") as f_in:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)

f_out.close()
```

I mocked up these three input CSVs:

```
file1.csv

| h1     | h2     |
|--------|--------|
| f1r1c1 | f1r1c2 |
| f1r2c1 | f1r2c2 |

file2.csv

| h1     | h2     |
|--------|--------|
| f2r1c1 | f2r1c2 |
| f2r2c1 | f2r2c2 |

file3.csv

| h1     | h2     |
|--------|--------|
| f3r1c1 | f3r1c2 |
| f3r2c1 | f3r2c2 |
```

When I run that program I get this final, merged CSV:

```
| h1     | h2     |
|--------|--------|
| f1r1c1 | f1r1c2 |
| f1r2c1 | f1r2c2 |
| f2r1c1 | f2r1c2 |
| f2r2c1 | f2r2c2 |
| f3r1c1 | f3r1c2 |
| f3r2c1 | f3r2c2 |
```

Comment: thanks a lot, will try it tonight)

Comment: it works but in my case It ignores 1 cell "mobile_phone" in each file.